# Parse Text in Python (Django)

Tags: python, django, parsing, loops

I have text that looks like:

```
Link(base_url=u'http://www.bing.com/search?q=site%3Asomesite.com', url='http://www.somesite.com/prof.php?pID=478', text='SomeSite -  Professor Rating of Louis Scerbo', tag='a', attrs=[('href', 'http://www.somesite.com/prof.php?pID=478'), ('h', 'ID=SERP,5105.1')])Link(base_url=u'http://www.bing.com/search?q=site%3Asomesite.com', url='http://www.somesite.com/prof.php?pID=527', text='SomeSite -  Professor Rating of Jahan \xe2\x80\xa6', tag='a', attrs=[('href', 'http://www.somesite.com/prof.php?pID=527'), ('h', 'ID=SERP,5118.1')])Link(base_url=u'http://www.bing.com/search?q=site%3Asomesite.com', url='http://www.somesite.com/prof.php?pID=645', text='SomeSite -  Professor Rating of David Kutzik', tag='a', attrs=[('href', 'http://www.somesite.com/prof.php?pID=645'), ('h', 'ID=SERP,5131.1')])
```

**Questions**

1. Does anyone know the format of this text?
2. How would I go about parsing out the values of the element `url` for example (from the above text):
   http://www.somesite.com/prof.php?pID=478
   http://www.somesite.com/prof.php?pID=527
3. What python library(s) would you recommend for parsing say this type of output, xml, json, etc?

I am just trying to `loop through the url` and parse the value of `url` only.

Keep in mind I'm using Django.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

**edit**
**current code:**

```
domainLinkOutputAsString = str(domainLinkOutput) 

r = re.compile(" url='(.*?)',", )  ##ERRORENOUS, must be 're' compliant.

ProperDomains = r.findall(domainLinkOutputAsString)

return HttpResponse(ProperDomains)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [Python Regexp](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
import re
text = "Link(base_url=u'http://www.bing.com/search?q=site%3Asomesite.com', url='http://www.somesite.com/prof.php?pID=478', text='SomeSite -  Professor Rating of Louis Scerbo', tag='a', attrs=[('href', 'http://www.somesite.com/prof.php?pID=478'), ('h', 'ID=SERP,5105.1')])Link(base_url=u'http://www.bing.com/search?q=site%3Asomesite.com', url='http://www.somesite.com/prof.php?pID=527', text='SomeSite -  Professor Rating of Jahan \xe2\x80\xa6', tag='a', attrs=[('href', 'http://www.somesite.com/prof.php?pID=527'), ('h', 'ID=SERP,5118.1')])Link(base_url=u'http://www.bing.com/search?q=site%3Asomesite.com', url='http://www.somesite.com/prof.php?pID=645', text='SomeSite -  Professor Rating of David Kutzik', tag='a', attrs=[('href', 'http://www.somesite.com/prof.php?pID=645'), ('h', 'ID=SERP,5131.1')])"

# Create the regexp object to match the value of 'url'
r = re.compile(" url='(.*?)',", )

# Print all matches
print r.findall(text)

>>>['http://www.somesite.com/prof.php?pID=478', 'http://www.somesite.com/prof.php?pID=527', 'http://www.somesite.com/prof.php?pID=645']
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you see my updated code? Is there someway to set my 'domainLinkOutputAsString' as a string? It appears its looking for a string or buffer.

Comment: `__str__` is a function. You should replace `domainLinkOutputAsString = domainLinkOutput.__str__` by `domainLinkOutputAsString = domainLinkOutput.__str__()` or even better by `domainLinkOutputAsString = str(domainLinkOutput)`

Comment: I think r = re.compile(" url='(.*?)',", ) is wrong, because now I am getting no output   . I updated my code to make sure I am not doing anything wrong. Could I just use a regular expression like: '^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]{1,4}$' to match somehow?

Comment: What is the output of `print domainLinkOutputAsString` ?

Comment: It outputs nothing, but page source shows: <generator object _filter_links at 0x10273e2d0>

Comment: Any thought here? are you sure I couldn't use a regex like url='(http:|https:)(\/\/)(www|a-z){0,20}',",    to match the "http://" or "https://" value with the url ?

Comment: You can do this, but a regexp matching all URLs can be very complicated if you want it to be exhaustive. You can find a good list of possible Regexp here: http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=URL&c=2

And in the example you gave, you will also match `base_url` values.

Comment: Great point - Will keep this site in mind. Thanks :) - I do believe it is a regex problem here

Answer (score 0):

We have a Python library to fetch and parse Google Search results accessible via 
`pip install google-search-results`

Uses:

```
from lib.google_search_results import GoogleSearchResults
query = GoogleSearchResults({"q": "coffee"})
html_results = query.get_html()
```

It works via SERP API's backend

More comprehensive options:

```
query_params = {
  "q": "query",
  "google_domain": "Google Domain",
  "location": "Location Requested",
  "device": device,
  "hl": "Google UI Language",
  "gl": "Google Country",
  "safe": "Safe Search Flag",
  "num": "Number of Results",
  "start": "Pagination Offset",
  "serp_api_key": "Your SERP API Key"
}

query = GoogleSearchResults(query_params)
query.params_dict["location"] = "Portland"

html_results = query.get_html()
dictionary_results = query.get_dictionary()
dictionary_results_with_images = query.get_dictionary_with_images()
json_results = query.get_json()
json_results_with_images = query.get_json_with_images()
```